# on_press in Kivy keeps running at start up instead

Tags: python, kivy

I'm having the problem where the application is running the on_press command of a button immediately before anything else happens. If I us a .kv for the layout it works fine, but I want to be able to manage the buttons using a simple list.

```
class AppBase(Widget):

    def Launcher(self, launchapp):
        os.system(launchapp)

    def BuildLayout(self):
        layout = GridLayout( rows=4, row_force_default = True, row_default_height = 100, col_force_default = True, col_default_width = 300 )
        with open('config.txt', 'rb') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="|")
            for row in reader:
                launchbutton = Button( text = row[0], background_normal = 'tile.png', on_press = self.Launcher(row[1]) )
                layout.add_widget(launchbutton)
        return layout


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        Config.set('graphics', 'width', 1920)
        Config.set('graphics', 'height', 400)
        return AppBase().BuildLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not passing a callback into `Button`, you're actually executing the function at that point. Change this:

```
launchbutton = Button( text = row[0], background_normal = 'tile.png', 
    on_press = self.Launcher(row[1]) 
)
```

To this:

```
launchbutton = Button( text = row[0], background_normal = 'tile.png', 
    on_press = lambda: self.Launcher(row[1])
)
```

Now you're passing in an unnamed function that will call `self.Launcher` when an `on_press` event is raised, rather than setting it to the return result of `self.Launcher` when the `Button` is created.

**Update:** for some reason, `on_press` and `on_release` events aren't actually assigned to callbacks in `Button.__init__`, the events themselves are just registered with no outcome. (This seems a bug to me, but I'm not familiar enough with Kivy to say for certain.) You need to explicitly `bind` the callback for it to work:

```
launchbutton = Button( text = row[0], background_normal = 'tile.png' )
launchbutton.bind( on_press = lambda widget: self.Launcher( row[1] ) )
```

Note that the callback actually receives an argument, which I've included as `widget` in the lambda.

**Update 2:** I should have caught this earlier, sorry, but I had reduced my local test case down to one button. When you do this in a loop:

```
funcs = []
for x in xrange(10):
    funcs.append( lambda: x)
```

Every call to `funcs[n]()` where `n in [0..9]` will return `9`, and not the value of `n` as expected. The lambda has created a closure which includes `x` from the surrounding scope. However, the value of that `x` changes over the course of the loop, and by the end it is `9`. Now all lambdas in `funcs` are holding a reference to `9`. You can avoid this by adding the *value* you want to the lambda's local scope:

```
    funcs.append( lambda x=x: x)
```

This points the lambda local variable `x` at the same object as is referred to by the loop variable `x` in the outer scope. It's more obvious what happens if we use different variable names:

```
    funcs.append( lambda inner_x=x: inner_x)
```

But the `x=x` form is very common in this case. So, to ensure that each button uses the correct value, you should be able to do:

```
launchbutton.bind( on_press = lambda widget, appname=row[1]: self.Launcher( appname ) )
```

Here, you bind the current value of `row[1]` to `appname` in the lambda's local scope, so that's what it will pass to `Launcher` when it's called.

Comment: That seems to be a step in the right direction, but the buttons don't actually execute anything when I press them for some reason.

Comment: Try adding `print launchapp` to `Launcher` to make sure you're getting what you think. It should display in the console when you click a button.

Comment: Nothing happens, it appears to not be running `Launcher` at all when I press the button.

Comment: The `Button` initializer isn't doing what we thought it was, I've updated the answer to show this.

Comment: The update gives me the exception `TypeError: bind() takes exactly 0 positional arguments (1 given)`. I tried `launchbutton.bind( on_release = lambda widget: self.Launcher ( row[1] ) )` (`on_push` wouldn't launch the command for some reason) which works for the most part, but seems to only be using the last line in the file for every button's command even though it works properly for the text labels. When using `print` through the iterative the entries show up as expected. So, my only guess it that the last `bind` called is binding every button instead of only the current one in the iteration.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the `on_press` keyword (note that this is "press" and not "push"), which I've now fixed in the example. The issue with it only displaying the last value is a scope problem, I've added some ways around that to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Working Code. create a CSV file with the following structure

```
1|hello
2|world
```

save as test.csv

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.config import Config
import csv
import os

class AppBase(Widget):
    def Launcher(self, launchapp):
        #os.system(launchapp)
        print(f"Application to be launched is {launchapp}")

    def BuildLayout(self):
        layout = GridLayout( rows = 4, row_force_default = True, row_default_height = 100, col_force_default = True, col_default_width = 300)
        with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='|')
            for row in reader:
                print(row)
                launchbutton = Button(text = row[0])


                launchbutton.bind( on_press = lambda widget, appname=row[1]: self.Launcher( appname ) )
                layout.add_widget(launchbutton)
        return layout

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Config.set('graphics','width', 1920)
        Config.set('graphics', 'height', 400)
        Config.set('graphics', 'maxfps', 30)
        return AppBase().BuildLayout()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```